# Firebase messaging token not generated

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(p0: String) {
        super.onNewToken(p0)
        Log.i("token", p0)
    }


}
```

This is my code to generate a token.

Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I have reinstalled the app but still couldn't find the token

Update:
I can now receive the token in the `onNewToken(token: String)` method but the `onMessageRecieved(message: RemoteMessage)` method is not executed.

I am using retrofit for making the network request and the response is successful.

Retrofit call:

```
private fun sendNotification(sendNotification: SendNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Log.i("sendNotification", "came here")
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
        val pushNotification: PushNotification = retrofit.create(PushNotification::class.java)
        val response = pushNotification.send(sendNotification)
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            Log.i("response", response.toString())
        }else{
            Log.i("response", response.errorBody()!!.toString())
        }
    }
```

SendNotification:

```
data class SendNotification(
    var notification: NotificationData,
    var to: String = ""
): Serializable {
}
```

NotificationData:

```
data class NotificationData(
    var title: String = "",
    var message: String = ""
): Serializable {
}
```

onMessageReceived:

```
private const val CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id"
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val notificationId = Random.nextInt()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)
        }

        Log.i("onMessageReceived", message.toString())

        val notification = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
            .setContentText(message.data["message"])
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager){
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "messagingexample", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onNewToken` only gets called *when* a new token gets generated. In other cases, you can access the token with `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token`. Did you try that already? If so, that value did `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token` return?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am able to access the token with `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token` but I can't log it out in the `onNewToken(token: String)`. What could be the error? I have provided sha1 and sha256 keys

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "can't log it out" there. Does your `onNewToken` nog get called, or does `p0` not have value you expect it to have?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added an update in the question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your keys provided are accurate and Cloud Messaging is enabled on your Firebase Dashboard.

It could probably be your service not running, try on an Activity and see if it logs anything.

My example code

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() { @Override public void onComplete(Task<InstanceIdResult> task) { final boolean _success = task.isSuccessful(); final String _token = task.getResult().getToken(); final String _errorMessage = task.getException() != null ? task.getException().getMessage() : ""; String ref = ""; if (_success) { ref = "fcm_token/".concat(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().concat("/token")); _firebase.getReference(ref).setValue(_token); ref = "fcm_token/".concat(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().concat("/uid")); _firebase.getReference(ref).setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()); sp.edit().putString("fcm_token", _token).commit(); ref = "wallet/".concat(sp.getString("addr", "").concat("/token")); _firebase.getReference(ref).setValue(_token); ref = "wallet/".concat(sp.getString("addr", "").concat("/uid")); _firebase.getReference(ref).setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()); } else { _warningToasty(_errorMessage); } } });`

Comment: I have provided the sha1 and sha256 keys. What other keys should I provide? `FirebaseInstanceId` class is not there now so I used `FirebaseMessaging` class to generate the token. I am getting the token in an activity but not in the service. How to fix that?

Comment: Your service is not running. Try to call your service with intent and see if this changes anything.

Comment: I did that but couldn't see the token still

Answer (score 0):

I have this entry for service in Manifest.

```
        <service
            android:name=".AppFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```